# 複数のテンプレートパラメータパックを持つ関数の推論に関して

Tags: c++

下記のコードで1.の方はコンパイルが通りますが、2.の方はコンパイルエラーとなります。
普通に考えれば推論可能な気がしますが、これはコンパイラのバグでしょうか？

それともそもそもインナークラスとアウタークラスのパラメータパックに関しては推論が働かないのでしょうか？

OSはWindows、コンパイラはMSVCを利用しています。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
テンプレートパラメータ'U'はテンプレートパラメータパックの後に続いており
'func'の関数パラメータから推測できないため、使用できません
```

**ソースコード**

```
#include <type_traits>

// 1.複数可変長templateパラメータ関数の推論

template<typename... T> class Class {
};

template<typename... T1, typename... T2> 
void func(const Class<T1...>&, const Class<T2...>&) {
}

// 2.インナークラスを伴う複数可変長templateパラメータ関数の推論

template<typename... T> class Outer {
public:
    template<typename... U> class Inner {
    };
};

template<typename... T, typename... U> 
void func(const typename Outer<T...>::template Inner<U...>&) {  // error!
}

int main() {

    // 1.
    Class<int, int> a, b;
    func(a, b);

    // 2.
    Outer<int, int>::Inner<int, int> c;
    func(c);    // error!

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パラメーターパックは関係なくて、`Outer::Inner`を分割して推論できません。

```
#include <type_traits>

class Outer {
public:
    class Inner {
    };
};

template<typename OUTER, typename INNER> 
void func(const typename OUTER::INNER&) {
}

int main() {
    Outer::Inner c;
    func(c);    // error!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: なるほど、そうだったのですね。ありがとうございます